# Setup Navigation Drawer in Angular 2 - Material 2

Tags: angular-material2

I am trying to figure out how to setup Navigation drawer as per specs:

[Material Design Specs - Navigation Drawer](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#)

using Angular 2 - Material 2:

[material.angular.io](http://material.angular.io)

I've got sidenav working but i been essentially fumbling how to setup the nav menu to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially it's a work in progress...
you can follow the status of the issue [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1728)

Comment: Thanks, it caught my eye the other week. Looking forwards to it being done